# Self page call doesn't update

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm trying to update a whole page in adf when you click on a link to go to the same page with new page parameters. If I open the link in a new tab, it works fine, but opening it in the same tab doesn't update.

I have a page that just displays the parameter value from the url, a link to the same page with a different parameter value, and an output text that displays the datetime. My taskflow starts by calling RetrieveDateTime() and then goes to refrestTest.jsff. The taskflow is a region on refresh.jsf page.

```
public class RefreshDC {

    private String dateTime;

    public RefreshDC() {
        super();
    }

    public void RetrieveDateTime() {
        System.out.println("DC RETRIEVEDATETIME");
        RefreshFacade rf = new RefreshFacade();
        this.dateTime = rf.getDate().getDatetime();
    }

    public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

The page fragment:

```
//refreshTest.jsff
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" layout="vertical">
    <af:outputText value="#{param.id}" id="ot1"/>
    <af:goLink text="RP PDTLS" id="gl1" destination="/faces/refresh.jsf? 
               id=1234567890"/>
    <af:outputText value="DateTime: #{bindings.dateTime.inputValue}" 
                   shortDesc="#{bindings.dateTime.hints.tooltip}" id="ot2"
                   partialTriggers="gl1"/>
  </af:panelGroupLayout>
</ui:composition>
```

The page:

```
//refresh.jsf
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
        xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:document title="refresh.jsf" id="d1">
        <af:form id="f1">
            <af:region value="#{bindings.refresh1.regionModel}" id="r1"/>
        </af:form>
    </af:document>
</f:view>
```

As i said, if you open the goLink in a new tab, it will update the dateTime, however if you open it in the same tab, dateTime remains the same. (The param.id does update in both cases)

Comment: Do you really need to refresh the whole page or do you only want to refresh the outputText Value with the current dateTime ?

Comment: Yes, this is just a sample project to try to address the problem. In my use case, I'll have multiple regions on the page that all need to be updated, therefore it doesn't make sense to partial refresh everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the taskflow. Basically, I made the button go to a new page with a region. This region has a taskflow that reads the url parameters and if it matches my conditions, links back to the original page with new parameters (toDocumentsPage). Otherwise, goes to a different page (searchResults).[Taskflow to refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PM6o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the whole page programatically by replacing your golink by an adf button with an ActionListener calling the following java bean function :

```
public static void refreshPage() {
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  String refreshpage = fc.getViewRoot().getViewId();
  ViewHandler ViewH = fc.getApplication().getViewHandler();
  UIViewRoot UIV = ViewH.createView(fc, refreshpage);
  UIV.setViewId(refreshpage);
  fc.setViewRoot(UIV);
}
```

Comment: This does refresh the page, however, the data contols still don't get updated, so it still has the same problem as just using the goLink. Rather than refreshing the page, I guess I'm asking how to do a new page request for refresh.jsf while you are on refresh.jsf

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to go back to the first step of your taskflow ? (Before calling the jsf ?)

Comment: Sort of, this is just a sample project with only 1 taskflow. I plan to have multiple on this one jsf. So it would either be something to do a fresh call to the 1 jsf or starting each taskflow back at the first step.